# What to do with questions that are duplicate on other SE site?

Tags: discussion, migration

So, this question got my attention, there's an exact duplicate on SF that has already been answered. Migrating it to SF would probably get it closed there as exact duplicate. Should we just close it as off-topic/delete it here and refer the OP to the SF version? Or should we migrate it anyway and let them at SF deal with it?

I'd be tempted to just delete/close it here right away and refer the OP to SF. But should we then just close it as off-topic, no migrating?

**EDIT:**

And this question is in a grey area really... there's nothing to indicate it's a production server... I mean, I run postfix on my machine... And I've seen loads of questions like those here. I wouldn't per se be off-topic here...

**EDIT2:**

My greatest con for deleting would not allow for a response to be left for the OP by users (like I did with the link to SF in a comment), so he'll be clueless as to where he might find his answer...

https://superuser.com/questions/243570/how-to-forbid-postfix-to-send-to-external-domains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it has no answers and it's a straight copy+paste dupe, flag it and I'll delete it. Migrating it to have it merged there is... pointless...

If it has some answers and they look decent, we can migrate it and have them merged. But more often than not, the answers a question receives on the site where it doesn't belong aren't very good. This is because most of the time users have a specific domain of knowledge and when you go outside of it, it often becomes guessing. So if they answers don't look too good, I'd say we delete it as well!

It's not a problem if the question is a duplicate, but has been edited to fit the site. However, this happens so rarely that generally my first to points apply

Comment: It's not an EXACT copypasta, it's just the same question by someone else... it has no answers yet. Deleting would now allow a response to be left for the OP, so he'll be clueless as to where he might find his answer...

Comment: I migrated it, because his question looked a lot better than the old one and the old one was over a year old. But it doesn't belong here, that's for sure

Answer (score 1):

I would not migrate if it is a duplicate on the target site, and has no answers here. That just creates work for the moderators on the receiving site..

Instead, I would close as off topic and put in a comment indicating they should check the other site, perhaps with a link to the duplicate Q if you have it...

Answer (score 0):

If they are duplicates on *another* site then I would close it as off topic. A question there means it's most likely off topic here.

Comment: Closing as off-topic just clutters the site, we might as well delete them

Comment: @Ivo: Close then delete sounds like a plan. Or a ♦ delete.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that Jeff has already answered this on meta.SO (will link later) and the answer was to close it here.  It's just more clutter on their servers, and of no use here.  If it's answered on another SE site, then that means it's more than likely off-topic here.

Comment: It's a grey area really... there's nothing to indicate it's a production server... I mean, I run postfix on my machine... And I've seen loads of questions like those here.

Comment: provide link please.

Comment: @wizlog since jeff already answered I felt there was no need.

Comment: OOps, really sorry.  If you edit your answer, I'll take away the downvote